# InteliJ/Android Studio shortcut for check returned type and help popup - mac os

Tags: macos, android-studio, intellij-idea

#1 shortcut

I was watching video about programming in InteliJ/Android Studio and I've Noticed
if someone has clicked Ctrl + Q in Windows in that case on "a":

```
val a = something()
```

it showed a small popup with information "a" will return String

#2
if i started to invoke a function openImage(//and here is my cursor) someone clicked magic shortcut then it shows what kind of parameters we have to put to this function

How to do that on mac os ?

Comment: 1. Ctrl+Q on Windows = Ctrl+Shift+Q on macos. 
2. Try F1 to show quick documentation

Comment: Both of the abocve could be achieved by enabling INlay hints for parameters and  types: https://i.imgur.com/mWXgogt.png